# How can i edit path of a jar in ant

Tags: ant

I would like to replace path of an existing jar based on OS .

some thing like below:
in windows : C:/apps/workspace/libs/rpm.jar
in unix : /user-id/projectname/libs/rpm.jar

Is there a way to remove C:/apps/workspace/libs from  C:/apps/workspace/libs/rpm.jar .

editing my Question to :

Thanks Liv, But i have lot of libraries like this. right now i am maintaning a text file called "build.start.properties" with all libraries some ting like this
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-servlet.jar
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-user.jar
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-dev.jar
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-soyc-vis.jar 
/log4j/X/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar
/GWT_LOG/X/3.0.3/gwt-log-3.0.3.jar
/GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-2.1.jar
/GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-server-2.1.jar 
/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-0.3.jar
/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-service-0.3.jar

And loading them to classptah using below target

```
    <loadfile property="jars.list.property" srcfile="mybuild/build.start.properties">
        <filterchain>
            <expandproperties />
            <striplinecomments>
                <comment value="#" />
            </striplinecomments>
            <tokenfilter>
                <ignoreblank />
            </tokenfilter>
            <prefixlines prefix="," />
            <striplinebreaks />
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <filelist id="build.libs" dir="" files="${jars.list.property}" />

    <pathconvert targetos="unix" property="build_unix.libs" refid="build.libs">

        <map from="C:" to="${unix.xenv}" />
        <map from="" to="${unix.xenv}" />
    </pathconvert>
    <pathconvert targetos="windows" property="build_windows.libs" refid="build.libs">
        <map from="C:" to="${windows.xenv}" />
        <map from="" to="${windows.xenv}" />
    </pathconvert>
    <path id="build.classpath.id">
        <pathelement path="${build_windows.libs}" />
        <pathelement path="${build_unix.libs}" />
    </path>
    <echo message="Build Libraries classpath: ${toString:build.classpath.id}" />
</target>
```

from the above target build.classpath.id looks like 
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-servlet.jar:/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-user.jar:/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-dev.jar:/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-soyc-vis.jar:/log4j/X/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/GWT_LOG/X/3.0.3/gwt-log-3.0.3.jar:GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-2.1.jar:/GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-server-2.1.jar:/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-0.3.jar:/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-service-0.3.jar

When i work on unix I have to pic only jar names from file "build.start.properties" and update path like this

/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-servlet.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-user.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-dev.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-soyc-vis.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-log-3.0.3.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-math-2.1.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-math-server-2.1.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-commons-logging-0.3.jar:/WebContent/WEB_INF/lib/gwt-commons-logging-service-0.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

Always use relative paths, that way you wont' be relying on library being at given location and on underlying OS.

Although this does not answer what you exactly asked for, but the suggestion will help you in the long run. Also, if possible, use Ivy + Ant (or Maven) to manage dependency.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  ant task -- the folliwng is taken from the documentation (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html):

```
<condition property="isMacOsButNotMacOsX">
    <and>
      <os family="mac"/>

      <not>
        <os family="unix"/>

      </not>
    </and>
</condition>
```

Comment: Thanks Liv, But i have lot of libraries like this. right now i am maintaning a text file with all libraries some ting like this

Comment: you can still do it and set up the an environment variable which stores the base path. simply initialize the path of this variable (let's call it lib_path) to the windows path: <property name="lib_path" value="c:/apps/workspace/libs"/> then you use a <condition> to check if it's unix or not and set the value to the unix path if it is: <condition property="lib_path" value="/usr/project/libs/">...</condition> and then use that variable to reference the lib ${lib_path}/rpm.jar -- does it make sense?